# Nothing is showing in Solution Explorer for Unity Project

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have a project in Unity 2019.4.0f1 and when I double click on a script in the unity editor it opens as expected in Visual Studio 2019. However despite having Unity Tools installed for VS, the class file does not have any intellitext and non of the objects are colour coded etc. It is as if it has simply opened a text file. If I look in solution explorer is shows nothing and says there are no projects. If I look in windows explorer I can see no solution or project files for the Unity Project...

What is going on? I have done many projects before (on an old laptop) and all of them worked fine... I have never seen this behaviour before.

Answer (score 19):

Ah, I finally found an answer

You have to go to Edit > Preferences > External Tools and Select Visual Studio from the External Script Editor dropdown. Then close VS and double click the script again.